# What is known that a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem 'would exist' at the time Andrew Wiles published?

Tags: math-history

I heard in a conversation with a friend:

> It was known prior to [Wiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wiles) [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) that a proof of [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) that a proof probably existed in the mathematics of [eliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve).

Now when I read about the [Modularity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem) - I find a discussion about the [Taniyama-Shimura Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Taniyama-ShimuraConjecture.html) (potentially two names for the same thing).

Now it appears Frey [suggested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem#CITEREFFrey1986) that Taniyama–Shimura–Weil conjecture implies Fermat's Last Theorem. This work eventually was [called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frey_curve) the Frey Curve.

But it sounds like other Mathematicians said at the time it was impossible. (Including Wiles ex-supervisor [John Coates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_H._Coates) and Ken Ribet.)

My question is: **What is known that a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem 'would exist' at the time Andrew Wiles published?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on the actual history or proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, but I'll try anyway.

According to a [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiNcEguuFSA) and Wikipedia, it was known that a consequence of proving the Taniyama-Shimura-Weil Conjecture was a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem. Simply, if you assumed Taniyama-Shimura was true, you had Fermat.

However, proving the conjecture seemed almost impossible. What Sir Andrew Wiles did was proving Taniyama-Shimura-Weil for a special case, which was later expanded to the more general case and became known as the Modularity Theorem, and then Fermat's became a corollary.

Comment: This is more or less what is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem#History). I have Diamond and Shurman's book on modular forms, elliptic curves and the modularity theorem, but he doesn't explain the history of the proof.